# Array into button title

Tags: objective-c

How can i change the text for button `answer1` to have the title from the array element `distance[0][1]`?

I've found this but cant seem to make it work

```
[answer1 setTitle: @"%@" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here is the full code:

```
NSArray *distance = @[ @[ @"Whats the best champion?", @"Veigar", @"Dr. mundo" ], @[ @"D", @"E", @"F" ], @[ @"G", @"H", @"I" ] ];

question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", distance[0][0]];
[answer1 setTitle: @"%@" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Where did you find `setTitle: @"%@" ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
NSString *theString = [[distance objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And then set your button text like this

```
question.text = theString;
[answer1 setTitle:theString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Note that you can also access the 0,0 element of distance like this

```
NSString *theString = distance[0][0];
```

But while the literals ([]) can be deployed to all iOS releases, subscripting can only be deployed to devices with iOS 4 and greater (and must be compiled with a base iOS 6 SDK or greater).

Answer (score 0):

If your value contains strings, you don't need `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. Just do

```
question.text = distance[0][0];
[answer1 setTitle:distance[0][1] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```